# How to run X-Plane 10 with Razer Orb Weaver and mouse?

Tags: controllers, x-plane-10

I just purchased X-Plane 10 but can't seem to use my mouse as a controller.

I believe this is because the game thinks my Razer Orb Weaver Gaming Pad is a Joy Stick.

As a result, the game appears to have disabled the mouse functions and enabled the Joy stick functions. Yet, since my Gaming Pad is not a joy stick, there is no way to use it to control the plane.

How can I fly the airplane with my mouse while still using my Gaming Pad for key shortcuts/combos? Is this possible?

Can I use my Gaming Pad as a Joy stick?

Also, please don't suggest I disconnect the Gaming Pad, the wiring in my setup makes this practically unfeasible.

Comment: Does your game pad appear when you go into the controller settings? If it does - you should be able to bind this up as you like, though I'm afraid xplane doesn't go to much effort to make this easy.

Comment: To control the flight controls with your mouse, click in the middle of the screen and a white box should appear - move your mouse in that box to control the aircrafts movements.

Comment: @TZHX No, X-PLane recognizes it only as a Joy stick (the only options related to how far one would push a joy stick up/down to move the plane, nothing about the controls).

Comment: Whether you can't use your mouse to control things like thrust, trim, rudder, etc. really depends in the aircraft and what functions are available in the 3d cockpit.

Comment: You'll need to adjust the bindings -- I'd suggest having thrust up / down bound to buttons rather than binding them to a control axis. I've had xplane working well (not the best it can be obviously, but usable) with an Xbox controller after a bit of tweaking.